# Uncorrect joomla image resize on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, joomla, joomla3.0

In Joomla 3.4, using firefox, the blogs images are not resized correctly.
The home page in firefox looks different than in chrome or edge or explorer.
Any tips?
Anyone has the same issue?
thx

Comment: What article images? The link you provided shows no article content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the CSS

Firefox applied to the image width of 100% of its parent element.

In this case it does firefox on < a > link element.

If you add in your css, to link element < a > a max-with, all work 100% correctly.

```
article a { max-width: 100%;}
```